# any quick way to add binary column by conditionally filtering dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I am trying to extract rows conditionally by looking up value in the columns, and intend to add new binary-valued column based on whether value has appeared in that row or not. To me, the idea is straightforward, I used [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) functions to do that, but I am having following error:

> Error in as.logical(test) :    cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector
>   of type 'logical'

**reproducible data**

Here is the [reproducible data on public gist](https://gist.github.com/forzaPhd/dfd874d569ad0a8183c59889fa98eb54).

basically, I need to value check in two different columns, then assign binary value to new added column. Here is my quick attempt:

```
f= read.csv("mydf.csv", header = TRUE)
df_new <- f %>% filter(str_detect(lelvel_care, "Intensive"))
df_new  %>% mutate(new_col=ifelse(. %>% select(setting, "ICU"),1,NA)) %>% write.csv
```

since I have been working on [python](/questions/tagged/python) a lot of time, using [r](/questions/tagged/r) to do such manipulation is refreshing my mind. To me, I might make the above code correct and efficient by using `dplyr` utilities, but not sure how to fix it and make it work. Any thoughts? can anyone point me out how to fix this? Any better way to do this?

**desired output**

I want to assign binary value (1, NA) if `level_care` column has `Intensive` value and `setting` has `ICU`, then export resulted df as `csv`. how to make my code works? any quick thoughts?

Comment: Is `setting` a new dataset

Comment: @akrun no, `setting` is a column in `mydf`.

Comment: What about `ICU`.  Not clear on thatt ifelse statement

Comment: @akrun `ICU` is string in `setting` column. that's key string that I need to look up. Idea is if `setting` column has string `ICU` and `level_care` has string of `Intensive`, which new column could get 1, NA instead.

Comment: The `ifelse` needs a condition expressioin as its first argument, and `select` is just selecting the column, if you do `select(setting,  "ICU")`, it can take both quoted/unquoted value and would be looking for column names 'setting', 'ICU' instead of creating an expression

Comment: @akrun in your code, looks `new_col` all has `NA`, and it shouldn't be. is that correct?

Comment: Can you pleaes check my solution

Comment: Do you have `NA` values in 'setting' column?

Comment: @akrun no, there is no NA in `setting`, `level_care` column. your attempt is not correct. any better idea?

Comment: okay, just looked at your github dataset, it is ssubstring, match, so we need either grrepl orr `str_detect`, updated my answer

Comment: @akrun I am curious about `grrepl ` solution. can you possibly correct my original attempt by using your updated solution together? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do  a comparison on the  'setting' column for the presence of 'ICU' string and if it is found 1 or return NA

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df_new <- df_new  %>% 
              mutate(new_col=ifelse(str_detect(setting,  "ICU"),1, NA))
```

thanks to @akrun:

```
f %>% mutate(flag = ifelse(grepl("ICU", setting) & grepl("Intensive", level_care), 1, NA))
```

Comment: I am wondering if we used your updated attempt, can we possibly optimize my original attempt? thanks

Comment: @beyond_inifinity your code is firsst filtering rowss and then creating column.  Iss that what you wanted

Comment: yes, basically I have two conditions in two different column, that was my approach, but I would like to learn if you have an efficient way to do this. thanks

Comment: @beyond_inifinity do you need `f %>% mutate(flag = ifelse(grepl("ICU", setting) & grepl("Intensive", level_care), 1, NA))`

Comment: right, that's what I want, it is easy. Thanks. big plus ++ )

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mix of mutate, ifelse, and grepl to get the column you want then filter by it.

```
df_new <- f %>% dplyr::mutate(flag = ifelse(setting == "ICU", 
                     grepl("Intensive",level_care ), NA) %>%
                dplyr::filter(flag == TRUE)
```